# Use one Associative Array instead of two index arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, associative-array

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b7ys1kek/10/)

I'm making a function to return the next nearest number and the associated color from a value,like if the value is `500`, the function will return `600` and its associated color `beige`. I'm using two arrays, one for the numbers, and the other for the colors to accomplish that. I 'd like to know if that's the right way of doing things like that. Instead of two separate arrays, can I just use one associative array to get the result?

Instead of:

```
var array = [50,100,200,400,600,1000,1500]
var color = {50:"red",100:"yellow",200:"Golden",400:"Black",600:"beige",1000:"pink",1500:"green"};
```

Is it possible to use something like that:

```
var array ={50:"red",100:"yellow",200:"Golden",400:"Black",600:"beige",1000:"pink",1500:"green"};
```

Here's the example:

```
var array = [50,100,200,400,600,1000,1500]
var color = {50:"red",100:"yellow",200:"Golden",400:"Black",600:"beige",1000:"pink",1500:"green"};

var getClosestValues = function(a, x) {
    var lo, hi;
    for (var i = a.length; i--;) {
        if (a[i] <= x && (lo === undefined || lo < a[i])) lo = a[i];
        if (a[i] >= x && (hi === undefined || hi > a[i])) hi = a[i];
    };
    var text = [];
    var text = [x+'/'+hi,color[hi]];
    return text;
}

var print = getClosestValues(array,1411);
$('.area').html('<div style="background:'+print[1]+'">'+print[0]+'</div>');
```

Comment: You will probably run into trouble using numbers as associative array keys as they are not the indexes. Better to use strings.

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing. Here's a fork of your fiddle, iterating over the associative array keys and not using the separate array: http://jsfiddle.net/65nb1cmo/1/

Since you're using jQuery, we can use their nice `each` iterator. Our strategy is simply to look at each key/value pair in the associative array (where the key is stored in `i` each iteration as before). We find the nearest `i` to the provided `x`, and then return it.

```
var color = {50:"red",100:"yellow",200:"Golden",400:"Black",600:"beige",1000:"pink",1500:"green"};

var getClosestValues = function(a, x) {
    var lo, hi;
    $.each(a, function(i, name) {
        if (i <= x && (lo === undefined || lo < i)) lo = i;
        if (i >= x && (hi === undefined || hi > i)) hi = i;
    });
    var text = ''+x+'/'+hi+','+color[hi]+'';
    return text;
}

var print = getClosestValues(color,1411);
print = print.split(',');
$('.area').html('<div style="background:'+print[1]+'">'+print[0]+'</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(color)` to obtain an array containing all of the keys in your object.